# Excel VBA row calling cell on multi cell paste (Not ActiveCell.Row)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script that I use the calling cell to do some processing.  It works great when I only paste it into one cell but if I paste into multiple cells, ActiveCell is always the first selected cell in the range and so all the cells get the same value.

How do I get the row of the cell that the function is being called from?

Example VBA - (in one cell do =TestCallCell() then copy and paste into several cells)

```
        Function TestCallCell() As String
            curRow = ActiveCell.Row
            TestCallCell = curRow
        End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to use ActiveCell in a UDF, as it will change as the Active Cell changes.

Use `Application.Caller`.  It will use the cell from which the function is called and not the active one.

```
Function TestCallCell() As String
    curRow = Application.Caller.Row
    TestCallCell = curRow
End Function
```

[image]